# Pymongo Regex $all multiple search terms

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I want to search MongoDB so that I get only results where all x are found in some configuration together in the key.

```
collected_x =  ''
for x in input:
  collected_x = collected_x + 're.compile("' + x + '"), '
  collected_x_cut = collected_x[:-2]

cursor = db.collection.find({"key": {"$all": [collected_x_cut]}})
```

This does not bring the anticipated result. If I input the multiple x by themselves, it works.

```
cursor = db.collection.find({"key": {"$all": [re.compile("Firstsomething"), 
                                              re.compile("Secondsomething"),
                                              re.compile("Thirdsomething"), 
                                              re.compile("Fourthsomething")]}})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building a string in your for loop not a list of `re.compile` objects. You want:

```
collected_x = []                            # Initialize an empty list

for x in input:                             # Iterate over input
  collected_x.append(re.compile(x))         # Append re.compile object to list

collected_x_cut = collected_x[:-2]          # Slice the list outside the loop

cursor = db.collection.find({"key": {"$all": collected_x_cut}})
```

A simple approach would be to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to build the list:

```
collected = map(re.compile, input)[:-2]
db.collection.find({"key": {"$all": collected}})
```

Or a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
collected = [re.compile(x) for x in input][:-2]
db.collection.find({"key": {"$all": collected}})
```