# Filter arrays against multiple regex matches

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I want to search MongoDB so that I get only results where all x are found in some configuration in an element of the key. This is a continuation of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126255/pymongo-regex-all-multiple-search-terms/25126500#25126500).

```
collected = []                              # Initialize an empty list

for x in input:                             # Iterate over input
  collected.append(re.compile(x))           # Append re.compile object to list

cursor = db.collection.find({"key": {"$all": collected}})
```

Now it returns all documents where the input list elements occur in any element of the provided key. How to only get results where the input list elements occur in a  element of the key?

For example when

```
input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

it would return a document with a

```
key = ['AHBKCOD', 'NDSI']
```

but not

```
key = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AB']
```

It would be great to return the matching element e.g. 'AHBKCOD' directly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mongo Shell Example

Setting up the test data:

```
> db.test.insert({'key': ['AHBKCOD', 'NDSI']})
> db.test.insert({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AB']})
```

Your current query does indeed match both records so `$all` is not operator we want:

```
> db.test.find({"key": {"$all": [/A/, /B/, /C/, /D/]}}, {'_id': 0})
{ "key" : [  "AHBKCOD",  "NDSI" ] }
{ "key" : [  "A",  "B",  "C",  "D",  "AB" ] }
```

To match a string containing a set of regular expressions and restructure the return object you would need to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/). The operations that are needed for this query are [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), $[`and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) and [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
> db.test.aggregate([{"$unwind": "$key"}, 
                     {"$match": {"$and": [{"key": /A/}, 
                                          {"key": /B/}, 
                                          {"key": /C/}, 
                                          {"key": /D/}]}}, 
                     {"$project": {"_id": 0, "key": "$key"}}])
```

This will return just the key you want:

```
{ "result" : [ { "key" : "AHBKCOD" } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

If you are running mongo 2.6 or above then the aggregate function will return a cursor just like a find query does. Below 2.6 and you get a single document with the top level keys, `result` and 'ok'. To pull out the results array you can add `["result"]` to the end of the query.

```
[ { "key" : "AHBKCOD" } ]
```

#### Moving to Python

There is very little work in converting this to Python as JSON *(and mongo extended JSON)* can be used without changing too much as they are often value Python structures *(dictionary, list)* especially if you are carefully in quoting keys. Python doesn't regular expression literals like `/A/` so this in one change we need to make, converting to `re.compile(r'A')`.

```
input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

collected = [{"key": re.compile(x)} for x in input] 

query = [{"$unwind": "$key"}, 
         {"$match": {"$and": collected}}, 
         {"$project": {"_id": 0, "key": "$key"}}]

result = db.test.aggregate(query)["result"]
```

I have assumed you are using a version of MongoDB below 2.6 here.

```
print result
[{u'key': u'AHBKCOD'}]
```

For just the list of values you could use a list comprehension:

```
print [res['key'] for res in result]
[u'AHBKCOD']
```